# Forced based physics engine

Tags: physics-engine

Most physics engines appear to use impulse based formulations.

Is it possible to use a forced based formulation instead with things like repulsive forces for contact constraints be defined by penetration depth between two objects?

Comment: Since physics engines work in discrete ticks, applying a force over the course of a tick is equivalent to applying an impulse once in the tick. What is it that you're hoping to gain from this?

Comment: It allows for more complex interactions

Comment: Probably more realistic too

Comment: @maxical DMGregory's point is that you can create the same effect as a force by applying an impulse each tick. For example, let's say you want to apply a force of 120 Newtons for one second, and your physics engine runs at 60 ticks/second. We can simulate a force by applying an impulse of 2 N for each tick for one second (120 N / 60 hz = 2 N/tick).

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by a "complex" or "realistic" interaction that can be simulated via forces but cannot be simulated via impulses? If you can exhibit a specific test case, users here can propose solutions that improve handling of that test case, whether those solutions involve new physics engines or just clever ways to use mainstream engines.

Comment: For example frictional forces are dependent upon applied force, you can also do more complex dispersion interactions via modeling it as a damped or nonlinear spring.

Comment: @maxical It sounds like right now you only have a vague hypothetical problem in mind. You should come back when you have a specific problem you've actually encountered while trying to develop a game.